# When i adding a facebook post comment containing '#' character through code it is not shown in that comment

Tags: c#, json.net

I am using facebook graph api explorer. When i adding a facebook post comment containing '#','&','<','>' character through code it is not shown in  that  comment

Comment: These are likely removed by facebook to prevent XSS attacks.

Comment: Have you tried escaping those characters i.e. replacing '<' with '&lt;'?

Comment: Thank u guyz..Jay can u please give me some reference for that from microsoft???

Comment: R Day replacement not works for #

Answer (score 0):

This should answer your question:

http://thenextweb.com/facebook/2015/04/03/facebook-might-be-shutting-down-access-to-hashtags-in-its-api/